# Unity2D random battle encounter to change scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm quite new to Unity. Trying to do my little project, but I got stuck. I want to make random battle encounter so it will automatically at random point changes scene. How can I do that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BattleEncounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    int counter = 25;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        int value = Random.Range(0, 100);

        if (collision.CompareTag("Player") && value < counter)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Battle");
        }
        else if(collision.CompareTag("Player") && value > counter)
        {
            counter += 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to load an entirely new scene or just change the background?

Comment: I am trying to load entirely new scene.

Comment: Your code will always change to the "Battle" scene.  Not sure how many scenes you have but you could load your scenes by index. i.e. Say you have seen "Fight" == 0, "Battle" == 1, "Kill" == 2.  Have a random range between 0 and 2 then LoadScene by that number.

Comment: Your code seems to do what you are asking. You will probably need to investigate more what's going on... for instance you could use [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) to see whether your `SceneManager.LoadScene` gets called

Comment: Any of this helping?

Comment: Yeah, got it to work now finaly :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I put my comment down as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure you can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will always change to the "Battle" scene. 
Not sure how many scenes you have but you could load your scenes by index. Say you have scene names and their corresponding scene numbers "Fight" (0), "Battle" (1), "Kill" (2). 
You could have a random range between 0 and 2 then LoadScene by that number.